# Postfix evaluation using a stack

Tags: java, stack, math-expression-eval

I just wrote the code to evaluate a postfix expression and would like it if someone reviews it for me, it works perfectly fine but I'm having trouble adding the character "=" at the end.

```
 public static int evalPostfix(String exp) {

    int res = 0;

    myStack list = new myStack();
    int n1;     //result of 1st popping
    int n2;     // result of 2nd popping


    for (int i = 0; i < exp.length(); i++) {
        char ch = exp.charAt(i);


            if (ch == ' ') {
            } else {
                if (ch > '0' && ch < '9') {
                    list.push(ch);
                    //          list.printS();
                } else {
                    n1 = Integer.parseInt("" + list.pop());
                    n2 = Integer.parseInt("" + list.pop());

                    switch (ch) {
                        case '+':
                            list.push(n1 + n2);
                            break;
                        case '-':
                            list.push(n1 - n2);
                            break;
                        case '*':
                            list.push(n1 * n2);
                            break;
                        case '/':
                            list.push(n1 / n2);
                            break;

                        default:
                            System.out.println("Invalid operator order!");
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    res = Integer.parseInt("" + list.pop());

    return res;
}
```

Comment: We are not here to *fix* your code. And it is also very unclear what you mean by "adding the character `=` at the end".

Comment: There is a similar post, http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/138894/postfix-calculator/138936

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Conventions**

According to coding conventions, Java class names should start with an uppercase letter. `myStack` should be `MyStack`.

**Variable names**

Whenever you have a comment after declaring a variable, *rename the variable to comment itself*.

```
int n1;     //result of 1st popping
```

Can be renamed to make the variable name "comment itself".

```
int poppingResult1;
```

**If this, then do nothing, else do something**

```
if (ch == ' ') {
} else {
```

To achieve the same effect, and make the code cleaner, write instead:

```
if (ch != ' ') {
```

**Integer.parseInt**

Now, it's not clear which datatype you get from `list.pop()`. If it is an `int` (or `Integer`), then `variable = list.pop()` will be sufficient.

If it is an Object, instead use `Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(list.pop()))`

Anyway, *if possible*, change the values you store in your `list` to always be of the same type (`Integer`, preferably). This would make your code cleaner as you don't have to use `Integer.parseInt` every time you pop something of the list.

Comment: May I suggest that instead of 'int poppingResult1' he should name it 'int firstPoppingResult' as his comment suggests that it's the result of 1st popping

Comment: @user1021726 Indeed possible, I was thinking that `poppingResult1` and `poppingResult2` would be more clear than having variations in the beginning like `firstPoppingResult` and `secondPoppingResult`.

Comment: about the naming of my class, i was in a hurry and totally forgot about the convention :/

Answer (score 0):

Consider using approach below where input string contains valid postfix expression.

```
static int evalPf(String str)
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(str);
    Stack<Integer> stack = new Stack<Integer>();

    while (sc.hasNext()) {
        if (sc.hasNextInt()) {
            stack.push(sc.nextInt());
            continue;
        }
        int b = stack.pop();
        int a = stack.pop();
        char op = sc.next().charAt(0);
        if      (op == '+') stack.push(a + b);
        else if (op == '-') stack.push(a - b);
        else if (op == '*') stack.push(a * b);
        else if (op == '/') stack.push(a / b);
        else if (op == '%') stack.push(a % b);
    }

    sc.close();
    return stack.pop();
}
```

In addition to simplifying the logic, I've dropped the `public` access modifier and used shorter names, with the goal of making the code shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! While you have presented a very nice looking solution, your answer doesn't actually review the code. Your implementation contains quite a lot of differences from the original (dropping `public`; renaming to `evalPf`, `op`, `a`, and `b`; adding a modulo operator). Are all of your changes intentional, and could you discuss why you made them?

Comment: Thank you. This is indeed an alternative approach that may be worth considering in relation to originally submitted code.

Comment: Dropping public and using shorter names is intentional. The goal is to make code shorter and easier to read.

Comment: Then I would say the `evalPf` is less clear than `evalPostfix. You could also use a switch on `op` instead of `if .. else if`